# Use sdl2-ttf to open a system font

Tags: c, fonts, sdl

Is there a possibility to load a system font using `sdl2-ttf`. I read the documentation but there seems only the way of loading a font with the full file path. On windows this would be a bit easier than in linux, as you can find the font folder relativly easy, but on Linux this is more of an issue as fonts can be stored in different places (e.g. `/usr/share` and in the home folder in the font folder). I did not find a reliable way yet to do this under linux, under Windows I find the installation dir of windows and append `\font\<name>` to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display text on Linux you need to go through harfbuzz-ng (for correct text shaping) and fontconfig (for font discovery and substitution), either directly or via a third-party lib such as pango or cairo.

Direct use of ttf files bypasses the font location stack, font substitution stack, correct opentype metadata parsing, it's a partial solution and won't ever work too well.

[For example](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3046) or [via pango](http://sdlpango.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! These are informations I can really good work with! Thanks!